pow and its relative error
Investigating the floating-point implementation of the $\operatorname{pow}(x,b)=x^b$ with $x,b\in\Bbb R$ in some library implementations, I found that some pow implementations are inexact.
The implementation is basically as
$$
\operatorname{pow}(x,b)= \exp(b\ln x) \tag 1
$$
Now let's assume $x>0$, and that the relative error inflicted by $\exp$ and $\ln$ is the same $\Delta$ with $|\Delta| \ll 1$
Then the result of the computation is:
$$\begin{align}
(1+\Delta_\text{pow}) \operatorname{pow}(x,b) &= (1+\Delta)\exp (b(1+\Delta)\ln x) \\
&=(1+\Delta)\exp(b\ln x)\underbrace{\exp(\Delta\cdot b\ln x)}_{\textstyle\approx 1+\Delta\cdot b\ln x} \\
&\approx (1+\Delta)\operatorname{pow}(x,b)(1+\Delta\cdot b\ln x) \\
&\approx (1+\Delta + \Delta\cdot b\ln x)\operatorname{pow}(x,b) \tag 2
\end{align}$$
This means that the relative error of pow is not $\Delta$ but
$$
\Delta_\text{pow} = \Delta(1+|b\ln x|) \tag 3
$$
So it is clear why the implementation according to $(1)$ is getting inexact, but I don't see how pow could be implemented with a smaller relative error.  (The targeted precision is relative because it is in the context of floating-point imlpementation).
I am not asking for a specific implementation of course, but for a different representation of pow that has a better error behaviour.  In the above implementation, the relative error of pow is unbounded even when the relative errors of exp and ln are bounded and well-behaved.

For example, in IEEE double the relative error of exp and ln is in the order of magnitude of
$$
\Delta \approx 10^{-16}
$$
so that the $e^t\approx 1+t$ approximation works well for a wide range of $t=\Delta\cdot b\ln x$, e.g. when $|b\ln x| = 1000 \approx 2^{10}$ then the loss of precision of the pow implementation is 10 bits.

What do you mean by "inexact"? You mean the error is too large? There have been reports of broken implementations of trigonometric functions in major software packages.

Your error will be large if $|b \ln x|$ is large, but then the approximation $\exp( \Delta b \ln(x) ) \approx 1 + \Delta b \ln(x)$ will be a bad underestimate.

For a working IEEE double implementation (which is the case for exp and ln), $\Delta$ is in the order of $10^{-16}$. So that for most practical purposes, it's still the case that $|\Delta b\ln x| \ll 1$. For example with $|b\ln x| = 1000$, the implementation of pow loses 10 LSBs in relative precision.

@njuffa It's clear that bumping the precision works, however I am on a very limited embedded system, and it's not actually feasible to re-implement exp, log and mul with higher precision. Moreover, there is no upper bound for $|b\ln x|$, though it would be some partial remedy. I just thought I had overlooked something obvious.

@njuffa The implementation is in asm: https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/tree/main/libm/fplib I'll have a look whether it is feasible. Also exp and log in that implementation are not as precise as could, but it's hard to do it within the same codesize / speed constraints.

@njuffa No, AVR has no hard FP, some devices don't even have MUL. Smallest devices where math.h is supported have 2 KiB of program memory and 128 bytes of RAM. The current powf (including all dependencies) already consumes more than 1.7 KiB of program memory.

The issue is fundamental and if we are limited to working precision then there is nothing that can be done to avoid it.
You are computing a function $f$ of two variables, i.e., $$y = f(b,x) = x^b.$$ Let $\hat{y}$ denote the computed value of $y$. In general, we cannot hope to compute $f$ exactly and $y \not =\hat{y}$. If we are exceedingly skilled, then our implementation of $f$ is componentwise relative backwards stable and there exists $\bar{b}$ and $\bar{x}$ such that $$\hat{y} = f(\bar{b}, \bar{x})$$ and $$| b - \bar{b} | \leq Cu|b|, \quad |x - \bar{x}| \leq C u |x|.$$ Here $u$ is the unit roundoff and $C > 0$ is a constant that is independent of $u$. The size of $C$ reflects our skill as computer programmers. This is the very best that we can hope to achieve on a computer because the basic arithmetic operations satisfy conditions of this type. Does it matter? Yes. We care about the size of relative forward error, i.e., $$R = \frac{y - \hat{y}}{y}.$$ The size of this relative error is controlled by the product of the componentwise relative backward error and the componentwise relative condition number $\kappa_f^{\text{cr}}(x)$, read this detailed answer to a related question as well as this answer to a simpler problem which nevertheless encapsulates the present difficulties. In your case, we have
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = x^b \log(x)$$ and
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = b x^{b-1}.$$
It follows that
$$ \kappa_f^{\text{cr}}(b,x) = |b|(1+|\log(x)|)$$
We conclude that smallest relative forward error that we can hope to achieve satisfies
$$|R| \leq C u |b|(1 + |\log(x)|).$$
Note that this bound is even more pessimistic that your original analysis because here I cannot assume that the relative errors for $\log$ and $\exp$ are uniformly bounded over their natural domain. If this is achieved by a library, then it is emulating a smaller unit roundoff.
In conclusion, your current implementation is about as accurate as we can hope unless we start emulating a smaller unit roundoff.

You may be able to improve on the error performance by replacing
$$
\operatorname{pow}(x,b)= \exp(b\ln x) \tag 1
$$
with
$$
\operatorname{pow}(x,b)= x^{Int(b)}\exp(Frac(b)\ln x) \tag 1
$$
where $Int(b)$ and $Frac(b)$ are the integer and fractional parts of b, and $ x^y $ is achieved by multiplying $x$ by itself $y$ times.
On the assumption that the error induced by multiplication is much less than that inherent in the floating-point implementation of $pow(x,b)$, you would reduce your error to approximately
$$
\Delta_\text{pow} = \Delta(1+|Frac(b)\ln x|) \tag 3
$$
